# Overriding Mudblazor expansion panel's padding

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor

I'm new at Mudblazor and trying to override the default padding of the expansion panel header. Here is what the html looks like:
[html mudblazor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn1Cg.png)

Mudblazor creates a div with a `.mud-expand-panel-header` in the background and that's the element I want to change the bottom padding on. I tried inline css and change the styling from the css file without success. I also tried to use `pb-1` on the `TitleContent` tag but that element doesn't take classes. Any ideas on how to change that?

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1: How to apply custom CSS (directly)

If you wish to override the `mud-expand-panel-header` style directly, create a new CSS file, include it in the `index.html` file and make sure it's loaded after `MudBlazor.min.css` to ensure it takes a priority.

Once that's done, add the following code inside the new file:

```
.mud-expand-panel-header {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

## Solution 2: How to apply custom CSS (indirectly)

Instead of modifying `mud-expand-panel-header` class directly, apply the CSS you need to any `mud-expand-panel-header` that's inside an element with a custom CSS class of your own.

### Example

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wumGaiveVFPlBBEe

```
<style>
    .custom-expansion-panel .mud-expand-panel-header {
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
</style>

<MudExpansionPanel Class="custom-expansion-panel">
    <TitleContent>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Filled.CheckCircleOutline" Color="Color.Tertiary" class="mr-3"></MudIcon>
            <MudText>Title</MudText>
        </div>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle1"><b>Price</b></MudText>
    </TitleContent>
    <ChildContent>
        <MudText>Age</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">Notes</MudText>
    </ChildContent>
</MudExpansionPanel>
```

## Solution 3: How to get Bootstrap working

If you wish for the `pb-1` bootstrap class to work, go to the `index.html` file and make sure that `bootstrap.min.css` is loaded a̲f̲t̲e̲r̲ `MudBlazor.min.css`.

That's what you may currently have:

```
<link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

That's what you should have for the Bootstrap class to work:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```